# Emacs org-mode: clocktable configuration

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know that I can generate a clocktable running C c C c on the block:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 4 :scope file
#+END:
```

or with the key combination:

```
C c C x C r.
```

However, the latter, generates a clocktable with:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree
```

(I want a block like the other one, with maxlevel 4.). How can I config the C c C x C r combination?e

Answer (score 2):

Customize the value of `org-clock-clocktable-default-properties`

```lisp
(setq org-clock-clocktable-default-properties '(:maxlevel 4 :scope subtree))
```

Or via <kbd>C-h k</kbd>`org-clock-clocktable-default-properties` then clicking on `customize`